# PHP PDO database connection

Tags: php, database, pdo

Hey fellas No idea what i'm doing wrong already tried all suggested idea on stackoverflow still not resolving error no database selected.

code:

```
<?php    
  include 'db_connect.php';    
  // create client table

    try {    
          $sql = 'CREATE TABLE client (
                  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                  name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                  phone INT NOT NULL,
                  email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
                  address TEXT
          ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB';

          $pdo->exec($sql);

  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {    
          $error = 'Error creating customer table: '.$e->getMessage();    
          include 'error.html.php';    
          exit();    
  }

  $output = "Customer table created succesfuly";    
  include 'output.php';   
?>
```

db_connect.php code:

```
<?php   
  $host = "localhost";
  $db = "hotelDB";
  $dbuser = "hotelAuth";
  $password = "+_90-w4903nsdkfn";    

  // connecting to DB using PDO

  try {    
      $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host = {$host}; dbname = {$db}", "{$dbuser}", "{$password}");    
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
      $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');    
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {    
      $error = "Error Occured While Connecting TO Database: ".$e->getMessage();    
      include 'error.html.php';    
      exit();    
  }    

  // On successful connection include booking form.    
    $ack = "Secure Connection established.";    
?>
```

you can see error in image. please help me resolve this. [image]

Comment: [Note that it's important to follow the proper format - no fancy spaces or other decorations have to be used.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn)

Comment: The same goes for the user and password which have to be addressed as just `$dbuser, $password`.

Comment: as of the `include 'error.html.php';` - you should be doing it inthe error handler but not in the catch block.

Comment: If it isn't clear from earlier comments, you _cannot_ have whitespace in the PDO DSN connection string. It must be `"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db"`. PDO stops parsing it at the first space and uses defaults, and that's what your problem is.

Comment: Note that the `"{$dbuser}"` and `"{$password}"` are unnecessarily quoted. Those are just method parameters, and can be passed as `$dbuser, $password` without any quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your connection to your database is wrong, since the error message of no database selected where to create your table to. Here is how to connect with PDO:

```
<?php

    $dbuser = "hotelAuth";
    $password = "+_90-w4903nsdkfn";

    // connecting to DB using PDO
    try{

            $dbPDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hotelDB', $dbuser, $password);
            $dbPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
            echo "Connection was successful";

    } catch(PDOException $e){

            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
            die();

    }

    // On successful connection include booking form.   
    $ack = "Secure Connection established.";

?>
```

Try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Please note that [you should never catch errors to report them](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)